# Creating irregular distance linear referencing hatches using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, linear-referencing

I am using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop.

I have stationing information which is placed at irregular distances from the starting point. These have a correlating mileage point. However, they are sometimes 0.1 mile apart and other times 0.5 miles apart. Therefore, although I have created routes from my layer, I cannot determine a way to bring in the stationing data table to create a hatching based on that information. How can I make my hatching irregular following a csv data file?

Comment: I've not had much experience with hatching so I may be wrong but the help file says _"Hatching is a type of labeling that is designed to post and label hatch marks or symbols at a regular interval along measured linear features"_. So I don't think what you are asking is possible. Hatching is for regular intervals.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that line in the help file as well. Unfortunately I am still new at this process so I was using the only terminology (in this case, hatching) that I thought was appropriate.